# Add product to Magento from codeigniter with authentication using Magento oauth api

Tags: api, codeigniter, magento, oauth

How to add magento product from codeigniter with Magento oauth authentication api.

I am new in magento.

I need secure way to access magento so I used oauth api to interact codeigniter with magento.

Thanking You!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this resource on Magento's website? http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html